# How to get Selected Entities in Salesforce.com Change Data Capture using force-partner-api-55.2.jar?

Tags: events, salesforce, change-data-capture

I tried getting Selected Entities from Change Data Capture in Set Up to display on the client app. I use force-partner-api-55.2.0.jar and then call describeGlobal() in ParnerConnection.java.

```
    DescribeGlobalResult dgr = getPartnerConnection().describeGlobal(); 
    DescribeGlobalSObjectResult[] objects = dgr.getSobjects();
    List<SObjectCache> selectedEntities = Arrays.stream(objects)
                    .filter(c -> "ChangeEvent".equals(c.getAssociateEntityType()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

It returns all Available Entities in the Change Data Capture configuration form while I expect to get Selected Entities only.

Then, I looked deeper into the DescribeGlobalSObjectResult to find out what properties can be used to filter and get Selected Entities, but I got nothing. There are no properties to target that info/setting.

captured image at debug time

[image]

[image]

So, how could I get Selected Entities from the Change Data Capture configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Read up about [PlatformEventChannel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventchannel.htm) and [PlatformEventChannelMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventchannelmember.htm), there are some examples for AccountChangeEvent, ContactChangeEvent and package.xml examples at the bottom of the page. You should be able to describe them and/or run a Tooling API query on ["member"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_platformeventchannelmember.htm).